# Read a keyed Kafka Record using apache Flink?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm using a value + record Kafka producer using:

```bash
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --topic test3 --property "parse.key=true" --property "key.separator=:" --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

But I'm finding it hard to understand how to read those Kafka records using Flink Kafka consumer `KafkaSource`. I want to  be able to do things like:

```java
record.getValue(), record.getKey(), record.getTimestamp()...
```

This is my current code that only reads non-keyed records from Kafka

```java
KafkaSource<String> source = KafkaSource.<String>builder()
        .setBootstrapServers(ip)
        .setTopics("test3")
        .setGroupId("1")
        .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())
        .setDeserializer(KafkaRecordDeserializationSchema.valueOnly(StringDeserializer.class))
        .build();

DataStream<String> stream = env.fromSource(source, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "Kafka Source");
stream.map((MapFunction<String, String>) value -> "Receiving from Kafka : " + value).print();
```

Can I get an example of what I'm looking for?

Comment: For a start, don't use `valueOnly()`

Comment: I have only used Beam, not Flink, but [looking at Javadoc, you need to use this to convert the raw `ConsumerRecord` into your own type](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/internals/KafkaDeserializationSchemaWrapper.html).  Then `KafkaSource<T>` will use that since it doesn't support having two generics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement a `KafkaRecordDeserializationSchema` (but not valueOnly), and then in its deserialize method you'll have access to a ConsumerRecord, and you can work with its key, value, headers, etc to produce whatever type you want.

There's an example in [Reading Apache Kafka® headers](https://docs.immerok.cloud/docs/how-to-guides/development/reading-apache-kafka-headers-with-apache-flink/) , which is part of the Immerok Apache Flink Cookbook. Note that while that example accesses the topic, partition, offset, and timestamp from the record's headers, it doesn't use the key, which is available as `record.key()`.

Note: I work for Immerok.

Comment: Is FlinkSQL any different? Like Spark Structured Streaming has access to key and value?

Comment: Flink SQL has the concept of metadata columns, which expose the Kafka headers. See https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/connectors/table/kafka/#available-metadata.

Comment: @DavidAnderson thank you for the tutorial!

Comment: The headers aren't the same as the key... SparkSQL, for example, returns key, value, and optionally headers as three distinct dataframe columns

Comment: True, I should have been more precise. The Flink SQL metadata columns for the Kafka connector expose a number of metadata attributes of each record, such as the topic, offset, headers, timestamp, etc. IIUC, the key is not included.